# Outputting data from database to HTML options and tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new in PHP.
I have a database with 5 columns. "id" "fldName" "fldPrice" "fldSupplier" and "fldPackage".

I have a HTML table with select options where I output "fldName" where "fldPackage" has a spesific value. I have made this work, but I would also like to output the corresponding "fldPrice" from the selected "fldName" when it's chosen. I'm stuck on how to do this.

This is my php:

```
<?php
function conTroller(){
  include("includes/dbh.php");?> 
  <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_price WHERE fldPackage='controller'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if($result->num_rows> 0){
  $options= mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);}
  foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
  <option><?php echo $option['fldName']; ?> </option><?php }}
?>
```

and this is my HTML

```
<td><b>Electrical package</b></td>
<td>
<select id="1" class="custom-select" required onchange="ePkg(event)">
<option selected  value="">None</option>
<?php conTroller(); ?>
</select>
</td>
<td>I want "fldPrice" to update here when I choose from the options</td>
<td>istL</td>
<td>Select controller</td>
```

Can anyone help?

I have been reading, googling and looking for similar problems. The biggest problem for me is that I'm not really sure what to search for.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. so you want the corresponding price with the name\. if so you could just copy the query and change `fldPackage='controller'` to you name variable.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like it to update the price, based on the selection done in the <option>. So for example, if <option> RC-Motor 1</option> is chosen, I want <td>Price of RC-Motor 1_here</td>

Comment: yeah so you need to have an input in this case that is your `option`, then you need to fetch all data out of the database after submitting your form and then you can print the data in your table. does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do understand the jist of what your telling me, but I don't know how to do it. I'm tinkering with it now, but atm I'm not making any progress.

Comment: You would need to take the `fldName` that the selected option submitted, and then add a condition to the WHERE clause of your database query, that selects only those/the record(s) with that specific value in the `fldName` column.

Comment: I have tried doing that now, but I can't find a good way of getting the output value from fldName, and using it in another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simplicity for only updating price when selectbox changed, I suggest to use [DOM Manipulation using Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

```php
<?php
function conTroller() {
  include("includes/dbh.php");
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_price WHERE fldPackage='controller'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if($result->num_rows> 0){
  $options= mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);}
  foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
    <!-- add attribute "data-price" so javascript can get price value from the selected option -->
    <option data-price="<?php echo $option['fldPrice']; ?>"><?php echo $option['fldName']; ?> </option><?php
  }
}?>
```

```html
<td><b>Electrical package</b></td>
<td>
<!-- add a function in onchange to update price whenever selectbox changed -->
<select id="1" class="custom-select" required onchange="ePkg(event); updatePrice(this)">
<option selected  value="">None</option>
<?php conTroller(); ?>
</select>
</td>
<!-- add attibute "id" so we can access the element to be updated -->
<td id="price-field">I want "fldPrice" to update here when I choose from the options</td>
<td>istL</td>
<td>Select controller</td>
<script>
// function to update price from selected option
function updatePrice(selectbox) {
    var price = selectbox.selectedOptions[0].attributes['data-price'].value || '- no price set -';
    document.getElementById('price-field').innerHTML = price;
}
</script>
```

For more advanced flow (eg: getting more product info other than price like description, etc), you will need a separate php file for displaying product info and fetch it using AJAX call. See [some tutorial about AJAX and PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Steps I did:

PDO is safer.

The first function returns data.

The other is making a presentation.

An additional div with id='fldPrice' will be the place to display the price.

A significant part of the code was done by javascript

```
function getPackage() {
    $db = conn();
    $sql = "SELECT id, fldName, fldPrice, fldSupplier, fldPackage FROM tbl_price WHERE fldPackage='controller'";
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function conTroller() {
    $options = getPackage();
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo "<option>" . $option['fldName'] . "</option>";
    }
}
```

```js
function ePkg(ev) {
    let prices = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(getPackage()); ?>');
    let select = document.getElementById('1');
    let fldName = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        if (prices[i]['fldName'] === fldName) {
            let d = document.getElementById('fldPrice');
            d.innerHTML = 'Prices: ' + prices[i]['fldPrice'];
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<td><b>Electrical package</b></td>
<td>
    <select id="1" class="custom-select" required onchange="ePkg(event)">
        <option selected  value="">None</option>
        <?php conTroller(); ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td>I want "fldPrice" to update here when I choose from the options</td>
<td>List</td>
<td>Select controller</td>
<div id="fldPrice"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to learn more about PDO.